# java - Printing values from List

Tags: java, arrays, list, for-loop, println

I have this code and it works fine when there are three consecutive values (i.e. *false, false, false, true* OR *true, true, true, false*) but when I put non-consecutive values (i.e. *false, true, false, true* OR *true, false, true, false*) it misses either 1st value or the last value.

The `if` statement is for the merge of the same values as if there are two or three consecutive values the code will show the output as merge, for example if values are *false, false, false, true* then output will be like below:

> [ 0 12 false,  12 15 true]

if values are *false, false, true, true* then the output is like this

> [ 0 10 false,  10 15 true]

But here is the **Problem** when I put values like (i.e. *false, true, false, true*) then the output is

> [ 5 10 true,  10 12 false,  12 15 true]

although it should be like **[ 0 5 false,  5 10 true,  10 12 false,  12 15 true]** as it misses the 1st value and same is the case with the *true, false, true, false* values it misses the 1st value.

Below is my code

```
package com.company;

import java.util.*;

public class Main {

static List<signal> list = new ArrayList<signal>();
static List<signal> list1 = new ArrayList<signal>();
static List<signal> res = new ArrayList<signal>();

static void add1() {
    signal [] s = new signal[4];
    s [0] = new signal(0,5,false);
    s [1] = new signal(5,10,true);
    s [2] = new signal(10,12,false);
    s [3] = new signal(12,15,true);

    for (int i = 0 ; i<s.length-1; i++)
    {
        if(s[i].v ==s[i+1].v && s[i].b == s[i+1].a)
        {
            s[i].b = s[i+1].b;
            s[i+1].a = s[i].a;

            list.add(s[i+1]);
            list.remove(s[i]);
            System.out.println(list.toString());
        }
        else
        {
            list.add(s[i+1]);
            System.out.println(list.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current loop does NOT handle all values, it iterates from `0` to `s.length - 1`, so if all signals are different and cannot be merged, the last signal is lost.

The minimal fix would be to add the s[0] to `list` and then iterate from 1 to `s.length`, thus making sure all signals are handled.

Next, in order to print each change to `List<signal>` it's better to implement a separate method `addAndPrintSignal`.

Also it is better to avoid hardcoding input signal array inside method `add1()` and pass it as a vararg `add1(signal ... s)`

```java
private static void addAndPrintSignal(List<signal> signalList, signal s) {
    signalList.add(s);
    System.out.println(signalList.toString());
}

static void add1(signal ... s) {
    System.out.println("add1(): " + Arrays.toString(s));
    if (null == s || 0 == s.length) {
        return;
    }
    addAndPrintSignal(list, s[0]);
    
    for (int i = 1 ; i < s.length; i++) {
        if (s[i - 1].v == s[i].v && s[i - 1].b == s[i].a) {
            s[i - 1].b = s[i].b;
            s[i].a = s[i - 1].a;

            list.remove(s[i - 1]);
        }
        addAndPrintSignal(list, s[i]);
    }
}

// tests
add1((signal[]) null);
add1();
add1(new signal(0,5,false), new signal(5,10,false), new signal(10,12,true), new signal(12,15,true));
add1(new signal(0,5,false), new signal(5,10,true), new signal(10,12,false), new signal(12,15,true));
```

Output

```java
add1(): null
add1(): []
add1(): [0 5 false, 5 10 false, 10 12 true, 12 15 true]
[0 5 false]
[0 10 false]
[0 10 false, 10 12 true]
[0 10 false, 10 15 true]
add1(): [0 5 false, 5 10 true, 10 12 false, 12 15 true]
[0 10 false, 10 15 true, 0 5 false]
[0 10 false, 10 15 true, 0 5 false, 5 10 true]
[0 10 false, 10 15 true, 0 5 false, 5 10 true, 10 12 false]
[0 10 false, 10 15 true, 0 5 false, 5 10 true, 10 12 false, 12 15 true]
```